In Mac Catalyst, what would be the simplest way to hide the title bar but retain its double click functionality?
After adopting sidebar / split view controller support in Mac Catalyst, there are several UI side effects that make the default title bar stick out and look inconsistent. If I hide the title bar however,
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
        titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
        titlebar.toolbar = nil
    }
    #endif


}

the ability to double click the top of the window to maximize it is lost. What would be the simplest approach to have both the hidden appearance, but keep the double click behavior?
